# How to recreate the "dangerous bend exercise" in TeXbook with `amsthm`

Tags: amsthm, wrap

I'm typing a document right now and have a `warning` theorem environment, created with `amsthm`. What intrigues me is that Knuth's *The TeXbook* managed to put the "dangerous bend" symbol in front of what appears to be an `exercise` environment. The symbol spans exactly two lines, and the bold `EXERCISE` as well as the following text wrap around that symbol, so that the third line starts and the left margin again.

My question is whether I can recreate this with preferably (modified) `amsthm` environments. I know that `trivlist` in the implementation of the environments causes problems, but it may be possible to recreate the look of `amsthm` environments without `trivlist`. Note that the dangerous bend comes even before the header (e.g. page 5 of *The TeXbook*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite good code in your answer, but it can be improved. In particular I use `\clubpenalties` rather than `\clubpenalty`, so we can

1. discourage a page break after the second line;
2. not worry about clobbering `\clubpenalty`;
3. reset `\clubpenalties` with a hook.

I also typeset the header *after* the paragraph starts, so we can use `\label` and not worry about spaces.

For a one line warning, we examine `\prevgraf` at the end of the first paragraph and, if it is 1, an empty line is generated with no possible page break.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{manfnt} % for \dbend
\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\newlength{\dangerwidth} % width of \dbend
\settowidth{\dangerwidth}{\dbend}
\addtolength{\dangerwidth}{1em} % add any extra space between \dbend and text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{warning}{o}{%
  % I mostly use equation counter, feel free to use any other one
  % default \topsep before theorem environment
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  % no line break after first line and discourage after second line
  \clubpenalties=3 10000 5000 0 
  % after first paragraph, reset \clubpenalties
  \AddToHookNext{para/end}{\clubpenalties=0 }%
  % after first paragraph, count the number of lines, if one add an empty line and no page break
  \AddToHookNext{para/after}{\ifnum\prevgraf=1 \nopagebreak\hbox{}\fi}%
  % specifying indentation of first two lines
  \hangindent=\dangerwidth \hangafter=-2 
  % step the associated counter
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  % store the start so to allow for \label
  \everypar\expandafter{%
    % remove the indentation box
    {\setbox0=\lastbox}% <----  !!!!!!!
    % zero width \dbend, shifted to left border
    \makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{-\hangindent}\dbend\hfill}%
    % theorem name and number
    \textbf{Warning \theequation}%
    % the attribution, if given
    \IfValueT{#1}{ (#1)}%
    % punctuation and space after
    \textbf{.}\hspace*{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
    % reset \everypar
    \everypar{}%
  }%
  % ignore spaces at the beginning
  \ignorespaces
}{
  % end the paragraph
  \par
  % default space after the environment
  \addvspace{\topsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{warning}[a note]\label{xyz}
    \lipsum[66]

    \lipsum[66]
\end{warning}

\begin{warning}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{warning}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{warning}
    One single line looks weird.
\end{warning}

Let's see the reference \ref{xyz}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. One problem I have is that as you can see in the image, the second line (starting with *justo*) has a bit less indentation as the very first line.

Comment: @Gargantuar -- I think the problem, instead, is an extra space before the "W".

Comment: @barbarabeeton AAAARGH! A missing `%`!!!!!

Comment: @Gargantuar Fixed, sorry for the silly mistake.

Comment: @egreg One last question: I see that you're using commands like `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `\AddToHookNext`. I read in `xparse` that `\NewDocumentEnvironment` will replace `\newcommand`. So should I learn these new commands and try to use them more often?

Comment: @Gargantuar These are the future… :-)

Comment: @egreg fortunately no one would be so mean as to forward your missing `%` comment to me.

Answer (score 5):

After much tinkering, I think I have a satisfactory result. I took the base parameters from `amsthm` environments and took inspiration from Knuth's *The TeXbook* code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{manfnt} % for \dbend
\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing

\newlength{\dangerwidth} % width of \dbend
\settowidth{\dangerwidth}{\dbend}
\addtolength{\dangerwidth}{1em} % add any extra space between \dbend and text

\newenvironment{warning}[1][]{
    \begingroup % local definition
    \stepcounter{equation} % I mostly use equation counter, feel free to use any other one
    \par\addvspace{\topsep} % default \topsep before theorem environment
    \clubpenalty=10000 % no line break after first line
    \hangindent=\dangerwidth \hangafter=-2 % specifying indentation of first two lines
    \noindent\makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{-\hangindent}\dbend\hfill}% % zero width \dbend, shifted to left boarder
    \textbf{Warning \thesection.\theequation}% % theorem name and number
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else % optional argument, check if empty
        \space(#1)% % if so, type optional argument in parenthesis
    \fi
    \textbf{.}\hspace*{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\ignorespaces % add default rubber after theorem header
}{
    \par\addvspace{\topsep}\endgroup % default \topsep after environment
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{warning}[a note]
    \lipsum[66]

    \lipsum[66]
\end{warning}

\begin{warning}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{warning}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{warning}
    One single line looks weird.
\end{warning}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have two questions:

1. As of now, the `\clubpenalty=10000` applies to the whole environment. Can I somehow apply it only to the first paragraph inside this environment? In *The TeXbook*, Knuth didn't solve this problem as he required that each "dangerous" paragraph should receive a dangerous bend symbol.
2. As you can see in **Warning 0.3**, a single line doesn't look very nice. Is there a way to remedy this? I would suggest that if there is only one line inside `warning`, one could use `\textdbend` instead of `\dbend` whoose foot and not its centre is on the base line. How do I detect this?

Feel free to give feedback on anything missing from original `amsthm` environments or improvements on the above code.